# Change Excel Formula Type to R1C1

Tags: excel, types, formula

I want use `Application.Convertformula` in C# to get R1C1 Type. And Addressing with R1C1 format.

Any one know how to use that ?

Becuase this not working ! :

```
Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("R1C1");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? `Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.Range[topLeft, bottomRight];`

Not sure what API you're using, but see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.get_range.aspx) about that usage, which suggests using [the Range property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.range.aspx) instead. Also note that both those expect two parameters and you're supplying only one with both references as one value. That is `"R1", "C1"` not `"R1C1"`, and possibly `Range["C1", "R1"]` assuming that's the range you want, with the top left reference first.